# Indian theme in real life

Tags: tactics, problems, master-games, otb-chess

We all know this beautiful theme of self-interference.

```
[Title "Loveday, mate in 3"]
[fen "3R4/5K2/8/4k1P1/4p3/7B/4p3/8 b - - 1 0"]
```

Solutiom:

> 1. Bf1 d6 2. Re2 Kc4 3. Re4#

Has such a motive ever occur in an OTB game?

Answer (score 6):

The Indian theme appeared in a game between Rudolf Spielmann and Siegbert Tarrasch (San Sebastián, 1912):

```
[FEN "..."]
[Event "San Sebastian"]
[Site "San Sebastian ESP"]
[Date "1912.03.12"]
[EventDate "1912.02.19"]
[Round "17"]
[Result "0-1"]
[White "Rudolf Spielmann"]
[Black "Siegbert Tarrasch"]
[ECO "C80"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "82"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O Nxe4 6. d4 b5
7. Bb3 d5 8. a4 Nxd4 9. Nxd4 exd4 10. Nc3 Nxc3 11. bxc3 c5
12. axb5 Be7 13. Qf3 Be6 14. Rxa6 O-O 15. cxd4 c4 16. Ba2 Rxa6
17. bxa6 Qa5 18. Bb1 c3 19. Qg3 Rc8 20. f4 Bf5 21. Re1 Bf6
22. Kh1 h6 23. h3 Rb8 24. Be3 Qxa6 25. Rd1 Qa1 26. Qe1 Be4
27. Kh2 Be7 28. Qf1 f5 29. Re1 Bh4 30. g3 Be7 31. Bf2 Bd6
32. Rc1 Kh7 33. Re1 Rb6 34. Rc1 Ba3 35. Re1 Qb2 36. Qe2 Rb4
37. Rg1 Rb6 38. Re1 Qb5 39. Qh5 Qxb1 40. Rxb1 Rxb1 41. g4 Bc1
0-1
```

I copy Tarrasch's comments to move `41...Bc1` from [here](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1130764) and the original source is Tarrasch's book [The Game of Chess](https://books.google.com/books?id=5XmN60ps1L0C&redir_esc=y) (London, 1935), p. 422-423.

> "The move Bc1 is analogous to the blocking move of the 'Indian Problem'; intrinsically it is an extraordinarily unlikely, even ugly move, since the Rook which is to give mate is masked. The 'Indian' character of the move is seen in the following variation: `42. Kg1 Be3+! 43. Kh2 Bxf4+ 44. Bg3 Th1#`. Another possibility is `42. Be1 Bxf4+ 43. Kg1 Bg3!` followed by mate or the gain of the Queen. The main variation is `42. Kg3 g6 43. Qh4 Bxf4+! 44. Kxf4 g5+`, and Black wins."